# Como pego valor na tag <td> em jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Como que consigo pegar o valor 1 e manipulá - lo, por jquery, que está dentro da tag td (quero que esse valor aumente, conforme eu clique em um botão de id = 'add-row'):

```
 <td>1</td>
```

Comment: Não entendi, poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: desculpa, esqueci q a tag html era interpretada haha

Comment: Podes usar `$('td').html()`  para ler e  `$('td').html('novo valor')`  para mudar... é essa a tua dúvida? Se explicares melhor o teu HTML é mais fácil senão somente `$('td')` vai apanhar as `td` todas.

Comment: acho q sim, vo testar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `$('td').html()`  para ler e  `$('td').html('novo valor')`  para mudar...

Dependendo do teu HTML deves ser mais específico no seletor `$('td')` porque assim vai selecionar as `td` todas. Para aumentar o valor a cada vez que um elemento é clicado tens de usar um oscultador de eventos, e sugiro que guardes essa contagem no JavaScript no exemplo em baixo. Porém sem saber o resto do código não posso adivinhar muito mais.

```
var contador = 0;
$('#add-row').on('click', function(){
    contador++; // somar +1
    $('td').html(contador);
});
```

**Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/tmx7bo52/**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar filter customizado. Veja:

```js
var text = $("td").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === "I";
}).text();

console.log("Text: " + text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td>I</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: obrigado! consegui!